# Using FrenchAnalyzer with Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, lucene, analyzer

I am trying to use the Lucene `FrenchAnalyzer` with Neo4J:

```
final GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("...");
final IndexManager index = graphDatabaseService.index();
final Index<Node> frenchIndex = index.forNodes("Entry", stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type", "fulltext", "to_lower_case", "true", "analyzer","org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer" ));
```

but this throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.fr.FrenchAnalyzer.<init>()`

I assume that I am using the wrong version of a dependency - does anyone have any experience using Neo4J with Lucene in French?

My dependencies are as follows:

- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.2.2
- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:2.2.2
- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:3.6.2  (based upon the fact that Neo4J uses Lucene 3.6.2)

(I am new to Neo4J and Lucene - I am just doing a poc for the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language specific analyzer classes of Lucene are lacking a noarg constructor. Neo4j however expects to have those.

Some time ago I've written up a blog post on this combined with a small github project that has wrappers for all the lucene analyzers, see http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2014/10/deep-dive-on-fulltext-indexing-with-neo4j/.